# Filename contains with <string>(starts_with or ends_with) in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dynamic-expression

I need some help that, I need to verify/filter the my excel input filename while creating a dataset, with some prefixed(like filename starts or ends with some string(ex: start/end with employee)). How can I implement the same in Azure Data Factory dafaflow?

ex: 20230831 emp_data.xlsx  ==> verify the file with emp_data string is existed or not?

Please let me know how to implement this. I'm new to ADF. Thanks!

ex: 20230831 emp_data.xlsx  ==> verify the file with emp_data string is existed or not?

Answer (score 0):

> Filename contains with (starts_with or ends_with) in ADF

To check file name, contain the substring you want you can use the dynamic expression as `@contains('filename','substring you want to check')`

you can follow below steps:

- Use get metadata activity to get the file names.
  [image]
- Pass this filename to foreach loop to iterate
  [image]
- Under foreach loop take if condition to check file name, contain the substring
  [image]

**It will check the file name, contain the substring and execute activities accordingly.**